How far is 2 meters in Path of Exile 2?
In the Path of Exile 2 passive tree, there are some nodes that are distance-based, for example:


Is there any way to see how far a certain distance is from the character so that I can kite more efficiently instead of doing something like, for example:


Might need to wait until they add training dummies into the game to get a definitive answer. Unless there are any skills which have a set distance to measure with?

Does this answer your question? There's an image depicting different ranges

@pinckerman great to see I'm not the first person perplexed by it, but it's not in the game (as in a thing I can do by pressing a button/opening a debug menu/etc.), and perspective may differ because you can zoom in/out. Also, unfortunately it seems that image was created using a feature of Path of Building, which is censored from the forums.

Future Reference: https://imgur.com/a/path-of-exile-unit-distance-radius-tBhn2#p5ZN7hu (the original thing that started that thread/the wiki page it referenced)

Please use https://pathofbuilding.community/ the one linked is not the correct site.

Assuming the first game and second game are the same in distance calculations...
The Wiki has an article on Distance that says:
0.60 m  

    Base range of unarmed melee attacks.[13][14]

1.00 m  

    Base range of melee attacks with daggers.

1.10 m  

    Base range of melee attacks with claws, one-handed swords (excluding thrusting types), one-handed axes, one-handed maces and sceptres.

1.30 m  

    Base range of melee attacks with two-handed swords, two-handed axes, two-handed maces, staves and fishing rods.

1.40 m  

    Base range of melee attacks with thrusting one-handed swords.

So pick a weapon, judge with your eyes, and do some math, I guess? Good luck!
